# Why I get a "Policy has invalid action" error?

Tags: json, amazon-s3

I created this policy using the generator, however I still get an error:

**edit**: I have used the policy generator again, reducing the actions, here is my updated script obtained with that tool, I assume that at least the syntax is correct:

[image]

I have then removed one action at a time, starting with `s3:CreateBucket` at this point I get a different error: `Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement` same if I only leave the `s3:DeleteObject` and `s3:GetObject` actions.

Comment: `s3:PutIpConfiguration` is either a future feature or a feature that was never released, or perhaps something used internally by S3... and I don't believe it's actually valid in a policy, even though the console may offer it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot removed but I have the same error

Comment: Oh.  This is a bucket policy.  `s3:CreateBucket` would not belong there.  Not sure if that would be it, but my next suggestion is to delete actions one at a time or in blocks to try to identify which actions are causing the error, and then come back and report your findings, after which we can look for an explanation of why the error occurred.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have edited the question with the update

Comment: [Here is a list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazons3.html) of actions and resources (some of which are not applicable).  If the resource type is "bucket" your ARN needs to be `arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name`.  If the resource type is "object", the ARN needs to be `arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*` or `arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/key-prefix*`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot in both cases the resource is of type `bucket` that's why I assumed both `s3:DeleteObject` and `s3:GetObject` (inside the bucket) would be accepted.

Comment: Check the list again.  The resource type for both `s3:GetObject` and `s3:DeleteObject` is type *object*, not *bucket*. For actions on all objects within this bucket, the ARN is `arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot corrected, set bucket for first and /* for second! Post as answer so we can accept this solution.